# Wso2am an application without store

Tags: wso2-api-manager

Please can you tell me how you created an application without using the wso2am store? because I need to make an application but without the store wso2am

Answer (score 3):

I understood that your question is to create application without using Store UI. You can use Store REST APIs. 
Refer this doc https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/apidocs/store/#!/operations#ApplicationIndividual#applicationsPost

Comment: I want to do is create an application without having to enter the https: // localhost: 9443 / store, or without using the graphical interface of the api manager store

Comment: You can use Store REST APIs. Refer the link mentioned in my answer